# Date format in swift language

Tags: swift

In swift Language
And I want to get date in this format:

yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff+zzz

Comment: you dont understand its cleary shown you i want date formate in this form:-  yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff+zzz

Comment: What is "ffffff" ? Did you read the date format pattern documentation: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns ?

Comment: ffff stands for .8524911 read my code above please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Sz
```

S is for fractional seconds and z for timezone. Please note that T is escaped

To convert NSDate back to this format:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxx"
dateFormatter.lenient = false
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) // returns "2015-09-16T13:51:53.316000+00:00"
```

Comment: You use dateFromString. It returns NSDate?, not a string. What you see is a generic format the print statement uses to show the value of the NSDate?. If you want to see it with specific formatting, you need to convert the NSDate back to string. I wonder why you convert it to NSDate, though. You ca get the result you want by `println(dateString)`

Comment: @AkashRaghani: *"but i want this 2015-07-06T23:59:09.8524911+00:0"* – That is exactly your input variable dateString in the question, so what do you want to convert? Please clarify the question with your input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: i want output in this formate 2015-07-06T23:59:09.8524911+00:00 date shoude be different... from your ans i am getting this 2015-07-06 23:59:09 +0000

Comment: Then you do something wrong. I get `2015-09-16T13:32:11.247000+0000` if I execute `dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())`. Please clarify (in the original post) what is your input and what is expected output, including data types. Your sample code converts string to NSDate, but your additional questions are about displaying formatted date string, which is pretty much opposite task.

Comment: sorry i am not getting this 2015-09-16T13:32:11.247000+0000 i am stil getting this 2015-07-06 23:59:09 +0000

Comment: You need to show your code and provide more details.

Comment: hello thanx for helping i am getting this output 2015-09-16T13:32:11.247000+0000 how to add : betwwen 00:00 from the following output

Comment: Ok, good, you are getting closer. This requires xxx in the format. I updated my answer, see above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89818/discussion-between-akash-raghani-and-mireke).

Comment: hello @mireke i wan to make application like just dance in objective c......like user have to act same as which dance image shows can u please help me what to do i am  shown different example of accelerometer and motion detector but i didnt get any thing from that.

Comment: @mireke here is my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739367/how-to-make-motion-controller-application-like-just-dance-in-ios please suugested if u know